# Doctrine 2 Xml Mapping not working

Tags: php, xml, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine

I have been working on **Zend Framework** and **Doctrine**. *I am a newbie so please pardon me for asking stupid things*

Until now everything was going fine, I was creating my entities and mapping them using DocBlock Annotations.

Now I want to use XML Mapping for my entities.

**I have created a class `Test.php` as follow:**

```
<?php

namespace Alpha\Entity;

class Test {

    protected $id;
    protected $name;

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setId($id) {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

}
```

**I am using the following for `Test.dcm.xml` for XML Mapping:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
        http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">

    <entity name="Alpha\Entity\Test" table="test">
        <id name="id" type="integer">
            <generator strategy="AUTO" />
        </id>
        <field name="name" type="string" length="100" />
    </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

When I try to update database using the following command:

`doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:update --force --dump-sql`

I get nothing, it says database schema is up to date. I get this message:

> Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current
>   entity metadata.

I have defined my entity in the module.config.php as well and defined to use XmlDriver, see the below code for that:

```
'doctrine' => array(
        'driver' => array(
            'alpha_driver' => array(
                'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\XmlDriver',
                'cache' => 'array',
                'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/Alpha/Entity')
            ),
            'orm_default' => array(
                'drivers' => array(
                    'Alpha\Entity' => 'alpha_driver'
                )
            )
        ),
    ),
```

Questions:

1. Can I use both DocBlock and Xml Mapping in one module?
2. If I want to use only Xml Mapping what is necessary to be done?
3. What is it that I am doing wrong above.

Answer (score 4):

1. Change your config paths because they pointing wrong dir, example:

   `'doctrine' => array(
           'driver' => array(
               'alpha_driver' => array(
                   'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\XmlDriver',
                   'cache' => 'array',
                   // do not use directory separator after paths
                   'paths' => array('.dcm.xml/files/dir')
               ),
               'orm_default' => array(
                   'drivers' => array(
                       'Alpha\Entity' => 'alpha_driver'
                   )
               )
           ),
       ),`

   2. File names must be for example for your case: `Alpha.Entity.Test.dcm.xml` there is lack of documetation about that but it should be that way

Comment: Your mention of "path.to.class.name.dcml.xml" save my day!